# PowerShell Script to download an entire folder to FTP

Tags: powershell, ftp

I need to transfer folders of data from our Unix environment to the network. 
One file transfer works great but not for folders. Newbie here.

```
**I got this code, looks great and simple:**
source = "c:\source"
$destination = "ftp://username:password@example.com/destination"
$webclient = New-Object -TypeName System.Net.WebClient
$files = Get-ChildItem $source
foreach ($file in $files)
{
Write-Host "Uploading $file"
$webclient.UploadFile("$destination/$file", $file.FullName)
} 
$webclient.Dispose()
```

My interpretation, not so good:

```
$destination = "\\fmh-utilzz\c$\visbkups\"
$sourceftp = "ftp://userid:password@fxxxxx.com/users/gmj0687/ftptest/"
"ftp url: $sourceftp"
$webclient = New-Object System.Net.WebClient
$Sourceuri = New-Object System.Uri($sourceftp)
$files = Get-ChildItem $destination
#
foreach ($file in $files)
{
Write-Host "Downloading $file"
$webclient.DownloadFile("$destination/$sourceuri", $file.FullName)
} 
$webclient.Dispose()
```

Any help would be great.

Comment: Welcome as a new user to SO. Please take the [tour] and also read [ASK]. [Edit] the question to include what doesn't work as expected `not so good` isn't helpful.

Comment: Don't try to roll your own FTP.  Check out WinSCP.

Comment: I will need to create an executable piece of code.   WINSCP looks like a manual file transfer application.

Comment: WinSCP is an FTP application that also provides a powershell module to use its methods.